# Error Installing R package 'clifro'

Tags: r, install.packages

I encountered following problem while installing package 'clifro'. I could not figure out what exactly is the problem here. I have included only the tail of the installation process.

I have been using R Studio Version 0.99.441.

```
** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Creating a generic function for ‘close’ from package ‘base’ in package ‘RCurl’
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
unable to load shared object '/home/sghimire/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/RCurl/libs/RCurl.so':
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3: symbol krb5_ntlm_init_get_challange, version HEIMDAL_KRB5_2.0 not defined in file libkrb5.so.26 with link time reference
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/RCurl’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘XML’ is not available for package ‘selectr’
* removing ‘/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/selectr’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘selectr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘XML’, ‘selectr’, ‘RCurl’ are not available for package ‘clifro’
* removing ‘/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/clifro’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘clifro’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/Rtmp2KL12X/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: You could try with `install.packages("clifro", dependencies = TRUE)`.

Comment: Encountered same problem.

Comment: So install first packages `XML`, `selectr` and `RCurl`.

Comment: @Pascal this is what i got while installing XML.
    

   checking for xmlParseFile in -lxml... no
    configure: error: "libxml not found"
    ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘XML’
    * removing ‘/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/XML’
    Warning in install.packages :
      installation of package ‘XML’ had non-zero exit status

      The downloaded source packages are in
 ‘/tmp/Rtmp2KL12X/downloaded_packages’

Comment: You need to install the header of the xml library. For example, on Ubuntu, it is `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev`.

Comment: Same problem with other two packages (selectr and RCurl).

Comment: For RCurl, you need `curl-config`, provided by `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev`.

Comment: Tried everything, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you successfully install packages `RCurl`, `XML` and `selectr`?

Comment: No, I am notable to install any of those.

Comment: Dis you first install `libxml2-dev` (or equivalent) and `libcurl4-gnutls-dev` (or equivalent)?

Comment: Yes, actually they were already installed.

Comment: So there is no reason for `RCurl`, `XML` and `selectr` to fail to install.

Comment: Exactly, i tried installing them separately but failed each time. However, i was able to install xml2, but i am not sure if XML and xml2 work in a same way or different.